# React Dynamic Html Tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say i have this react component refering to a TextInput.
I want this component to be a

`<input type="text">` and a `<textarea>` as well, but with no ifs on it, as being passed throw props, however my renderer got extra stuff on the element as follows:

```
   render() {
      return (
            <label>
            <strong>{this.props.name}</strong>
               <input type="text" ref={ component => { this.input = component; } } name={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />
            </label>
      )
   }
```

My original idea was doing something like this

```
myInputProps = { type: (<input type="text"/>) }
```

So in my element i woul render this simply as

```
  {this.props.type}
```

However how could i pass all those extra stuff to the element such as the ref, name, onchange etc ? What would be a good aproach on this problem ? I could do some ifs and check what should i render depending on the component state etc, but i`m not sure that would be the best.

Comment: Just make 2 different components `<Textinput>` and `<TextAreaInput>` and pass props (like `type` and `inputRef` etc.).  Either that or use `this.props.children`.

Comment: It is a solution however i was tryng something more abstract, if possible of course.

Comment: why do you want to be more abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
render() {
  var input = this.props.type;
  input.props = { 
      ...input.props, 
      ref: (component) => { this.input = component;},
      onChange: this.handleChange,
      value: this.state.value
  };

  return (
        <label>
           <strong>{this.props.name}</strong>
           {input}
        </label>
  )
}
```

Comment: not sure I like mutating the `input.props` like this.  Seems strange to set `props` on an instance.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems that is the only way if the input is passed from outside and you want to change the props of it.

Comment: Can you give more details on your comment. I didn't get what you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  return (
        <label>
        <strong>{this.props.name}</strong>
           {this.props.children}
        </label>
  )}
```

Comment: And for `textarea`?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can wrap either an input or textarea accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I'd advocate using separate `<TextInput>` and `<TextArea>` components, but if you really need the flexiblity, use render props:

Using a `render` prop:

```
render() {
      const props = {
          ref: component => this.input = component,
          name: this.props.name,
          onChange: this.handleChange
      };
      return (
            <label>
            <strong>{this.props.name}</strong>
               { this.props.render(props) }
            </label>
      )
   }
```

Then use it like:

```
<TextInput name="foo" render={ props => <input ...props /> } />
```